# Nginx reload error in mac osx

Tags: macos, nginx

Greeting, 
i have a server installed nginx streaming 
i did stop nginx and then did reload it, but it show me below error and was not start:

```
nginx -s stop 
nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No     such file or directory)
```

i did below command and nothing:

```
sudo nginx 
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

how i can resolve it? 
can anyone give me PID file content so i can creat it (Fake).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fix it by removing `nginx.pid` in `/usr/local/var/run` and then using `brew services start nginx`

Comment: Im my case if I do so  I then get an error saying `nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Comment: Did you fix this? Getting same issue now.

Comment: I am running with the same issue. In my case, the file nginx.pid does not exist in that location. so How to fix it in this case?

Comment: Try `service nginx start`

Answer (score 3):

your nginx does not start, start the nginx use `nginx` command

Answer (score 2):

I was using nginx installed by homebrew,

I deleted /opt/homebrew/var/run/nginx.pid (the location may vary depending on the version you are using)

```
sudo rm /opt/homebrew/var/run/nginx.pid
```

Then restarted the service

```
 brew services restart nginx
```

You may start it if it is not already running

```
brew services start nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by run `sudo nginx`, After that you can run `sudo nginx -s reload` normaly.

Answer (score 0):

For linux users:
1- verify the location of nginx.pid from /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
when you got the pid location delete it.

2- permission issue; try to chown user:user /run/nginx.pid
then restart nginx.